# How to download image from Url using of NSURlConnection to save in phone cache

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, nsurlconnection

I am using NSUrlconnection to call to api but now i have also receive image from api so i don't know how to load the image & save into phones local memory because these images are further using in app . please help me. how to use & show image from local save.I am using below function to load the image but  NSURLSession.sharedSession() are not going to inside the queue.

```
 func saveImage(url:NSString,image_name1:NSString)
    {
        NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(NSURL(string: url as String)!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in

                        if error != nil {
                            print(error)
                            return
                        }
                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                            let image = UIImage(data: data!)
                            var paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
                            let documentsDirectory = paths[0]
                            let path = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: documentsDirectory).URLByAppendingPathComponent(image_name1 as String)!.absoluteString
                            print(" file path is \(path)")
                            let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image!)
                            data!.writeToFile(path!, atomically: true)

                        })

                    }).resume()



   }
```

Comment: `NSURLConnection` is deprecated you should go with `NSURLSession`

Comment: bro but it is working in my code

Answer (score 0):

for save

```
var image = ....  // However you create/get a UIImage
let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as String
let destinationPath = documentsPath.stringByAppendingPathComponent("filename.jpg")
UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image,1.0).writeToFile(destinationPath, atomically: true)
```

for cash

https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher

pod 'Kingfisher'

```
let url = URL(string: "url_of_your_image")
imageView.kf.setImage(with: url)
```

it's automatic cash images

Comment: bro my requirment is to store first local memory & then using these images

Comment: var image = ....  // However you create/get a UIImage
let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as String
let destinationPath = documentsPath.stringByAppendingPathComponent("filename.jpg")
UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image,1.0).writeToFile(destinationPath, atomically: true)

Comment: bro using of nsurlconnection how to load the image

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url!) //make sure your image in this url does exist, otherwise unwrap in a if let check / try-catch
imageView.image = UIImage(data: data!)
```

From : https://stackoverflow.com/a/27517280/3901620

Comment: let data = try? NSData(contentsOfURL:(NSURL(string: url as String))!)
        let image =  UIImage(data: data!!)
        var paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
        let documentsDirectory = paths[0]
        let path = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: documentsDirectory).URLByAppendingPathComponent(image_name1 as String)!.absoluteString
        print(" file path is \(path)")
        let data1 = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image!)
      let result =  data1!.writeToFile(path!, atomically: true)
        print("result is \(result)")
it show false

Comment: did you get bytes in data ?